# When using setcap, where is the permission stored?

Tags: capabilities, setcap

Using `setcap` to give additional permissions to a binary should write the new permission somewhere, on storage or in memory, where is it stored ?

Using `lsof` as is doesn't work because the process disappear too quickly.

Comment: Use another process. Make a copy of `/usr/bin/sleep` and give the capabilities to this copy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Extended permissions such as access control lists set by `setfacl` and capability flags set by `setcap` are stored in the same place as traditional permissions and set[ug]id flags set by `chmod`: in the file's inode.

(They may actually be stored in a separate block on the disk, because an inode has a fixed size which has room for the traditional permission bits but not for the potentially unbounded extended permissions. But that only matters in rare cases, such as having to care that `setcap` could run out of disk space. But even `chmod` could run out of disk space on a system that uses deduplication!)

GNU ls doesn't display a file's setcap attributes. You can display them with [`getcap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/getcap.8.html). You can list all the extended attributes with [`getfattr -d -m -`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html); the setcap attribute is called `security.capability` and it is encoded in a binary format which `getcap` decodes for you.

Answer (score 5):

setcap sets file capabilities which are stored in filesystem extended attribute. These are explained in [`man 7 capabilities`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

> The file capability sets are stored in an extended attribute (see setxattr(2)) named security.capability.

You can inspect the capabilities of a running process by examining *CapInh/CapPrm/CapEff* fields in [`/proc/PID/status`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). See my answer to "*[How to set capabilities with setcap command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389879/how-to-set-capabilities-with-setcap-command/389903#389903)*" for explanation on how the capabilities are applied to process at exec.

Comment: capsh --decode= could come handy to get human readable data.