# How to set capabilities with setcap command?

Tags: capabilities, setcap

I would like to set up wpa_supplicant and *openvpn* to run as non-root user, like the recommended setup for *wireshark*. I can't find any documentation for what  `+eip` in this example means:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_dac_override+eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Comment: The one answer this question has so far is very difficult to understand. I think an additional answer is still needed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way capabilities work in Linux is documented in [`man 7 capabilities`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities).

**Processes' capabilities** in the *effective set* are against which **permission checks** are done. *File capabilities* are used during an *execv* call (which happens when you want to run another program<sup>1</sup>) to calculate the new capability sets for the process.

Files have two sets for capabilities, *permitted* and *inheritable* and *effective bit*.

Processes have three capability sets: *effective*, *permitted* and *inheritable*. There is also a bounding set, which limits which capabilities may be added later to a process' inherited set and affects how capabilities are calculated during a call to *execv*. Capabilities can only be dropped from the *bounding set*, not added.

Permissions checks for a process are checked against the process' *effective set*. A process can raise its capabilities from the *permitted* to the *effective set* (using  [*capget*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/capget) and [*capset*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/capset) syscalls, the recommended APIs are respectively [*cap_get_proc*](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_get_proc) and [*cap_set_proc*](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_set_proc)).

*Inheritable* and *bounding* sets and *file capabilities* come into play during an *execv* syscall. During *execv*, new *effective* and *permitted* sets are calculated and the *inherited* and *bounding* sets stay unchanged. The algorithm is described in the `capabilities` man page:

> ```
> P'(permitted) = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) |
>                 (F(permitted) & cap_bset)
>
> P'(effective) = F(effective) ? P'(permitted) : 0
>
> P'(inheritable) = P(inheritable)    [i.e., unchanged]
> ```
>
> Where **P** is the old capability set, **P'** is the capability set after *execv* and **F** is the file capability set.

If a capability is in both processes' *inheritable* set and the file's *inheritable* set (intersection/logical AND), it is added to the *permitted set*. The file's *permitted set* is added (union/logical OR) to it (if it is within the bounding set).

If the *effective bit* in file capabilities is set, all *permitted* capabilities are raised to *effective* after *execv*.

Capabilities in kernel are actually set for threads, but regarding file capabilities this distinction is usually relevant only if the process alters its own capabilities.

In your example capabilities `cap_net_raw` , `cap_net_admin` and `cap_dac_override` are added to the *inherited* and *permitted* sets and the *effective* bit is set. When your binary is executed, the process will have those capabilities in the *effective* and *permitted* sets if they are not limited by a bounding set.

<sub>[1] For the *fork* syscall, all the capabilities and the bounding set are copied from parent process. Changes in uid also have their own semantics for how capabilities are set in the *effective* and *permitted* sets.</sub>

Comment: So is P(inherited, bounding) like a template stored with the files or just user wide? (how would a new process (before execv) have any capabilities) Also what is the syntax for removing I'm guessing '-e' removes effective bit , 'setcap capabilities_name -ip' to remove inherent & permitted capabilities

Comment: Process before doesn't necessarily have any. If the file has `+ep` the process will gain those capabilities. Usually bounding set is full by default; no capabilities are masked, otherwise no process could ever get any capabilities.

Comment: But then what's the point in P'(permitted) = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable). Thanks a ton btw!

Comment: A process can regain a capability it had previously. It can drop capabilities from *permitted* and *effective* sets and gain them again if the file has `+i` for those capabilities.

Comment: Oh a security feature? so say ' ip r add default 192.168.1..1 via nic' needs  cap_net_admin where as 'ip r list' doesn't

Comment: If the file has only `+i`, only processes which already have the same capability in *inheritable* set can gain it as *permitted* (or *effective* if `+ie`) via *execv*. For processes without capabilities it doesn't add any capabilities.

Comment: This answer and the docs it references do not depart from the grand tradition of unintelligible man pages, useful only as reminders to readers who already attended Un*x summer camp.  The answers at https://unix.StackExchange.com/questions/298893/why-are-not-all-permitted-capabilities-of-a-linux-process-effective-all-the-time are more useful.

Comment: You should have shown an example command instead of pasting from the man pages, in my opinion.

Comment: i think i need to go to one of those summer camps

Answer (score 9):

**Setting a capability on a file**

`sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=ep' file_name`

**Setting multiple capabilities on a file**

`sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=ep cap_sys_admin=ep' file_name`

**Removing all capabilities from a file**

`sudo setcap -r file_name`

**Checking capabilities for a file**

`getcap file_name`

**List of possible capabilities (some are really interesting)**

https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities

**Pitfall:** setting capabilities does not really work for scripts. If you want your Python script to work, you need to set the capabilities on the Python executable itself. It's not ideal.

**Note:** `setcap` always overwrites the entire capability set when you run it. Most of the time, you see examples using `setcap` with `+` or `-` syntax, which I believe is a confusing piece of junk and does NOT work as you would expect from other tools like `chmod`. You can't use `setcap` multiple times to add different capabilities, it needs to be done in a single command.

Comment: What is `ep` (in `=ep`) and are there other values that can be assigned to the keys?